# Playframework 2.x Apache Tika issue

Tags: java, parsing, playframework, playframework-2.0, apache-tika

i am uploading file using upload from then after getting uploaded file i am using `Apache tika` top extract `content,metadata` from  uploaded file  and applying but some error is coming

have a look of my **playframework controller code**  :

```
public static Result upload() {
        MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        FilePart picture = body.getFile("doc");
        if (picture != null) {

            String fileName = picture.getFilename();
            int eof = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
            String ext = fileName.substring(eof + 1);
            
            file = picture.getFile();
            
            InputStream is;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Parser ps=new AutoDetectParser();
            
            BodyContentHandler bch=new BodyContentHandler();
            
            Metadata metadata=new Metadata();
            
            try {
                ps.parse(is, bch, metadata, new ParseContext());
            } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            String sw=bch.toString();

            
            return ok(sw+" entity extracted and saved" + ext);
      }else {
        flash("error", "Missing file");
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }
```

but when i am **running this web application** i am using `commands`:

```
rahul@inext:~/playframwrk apps/EntWebPrj$ play
        [info] Loading project definition from /home/rahul/playframwrk apps/EntWebPrj/project
[info] Set current project to EntWebPrj (in build file:/home/rahul/playframwrk%20apps/EntWebPrj/)
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/
play! 2.1.2 (using Java 1.7.0_25 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org
> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.
[EntWebPrj] $ ~run
```

it is giving **error** :

if you want to see **full error** then [full error](http://textsave.de/KYJ)

and some of **error** is :

```
sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error: package org.apache.tika.exception does not exist]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:346) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
[warn] play - No application found at invoker init
```

**i added tika jar file.**

Give me some idea to fix this issue.

Comment: And how exactly did you add the jar to the project?

Comment: i am using eclipse. i did right click on project and in properties of project there is a tab 'java build path' and after this click on java build path and get libraries and click on add external jars and select tika jar.

Comment: Play in console wouldn't be aware of your Eclipse changes, would it?

Comment: @maksimov After load tika jar file i reaload my play framework app but it is giving error.

Comment: Make sure the Tika jars (and their dependencies!) are available at runtime too. It sounds like you've only set them up for compile time, so they're not present when your code executes

Comment: how to do this @Gagravarr

Comment: I've no idea, I've never come across your framework before. However, I can say you don't have a Tika issue, you have a build/install issue with your framework!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a dependency to Playframework can be done in two ways :

1. Unmanaged dependencies : directly add the jar in a /lib folder at the root of your project and restart your play application.
2. Managed dependencies : Add the jar to your build.sbt file as in the following example :

   ```
   val appDependencies = Seq(
       jdbc, cache,
       "org.apache.tika" % "tika" % "0.3"
   )
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to also add the tika-parsers-X.Y.jar file (where X.Y is the version e.g., 1.4).

Comment: give me link of tika-parsers-1.4.jar file @Chris

Comment: If you're using maven, just add a dependency on `tika-parsers` at version `1.4` and maven will suck down all the jars and their dependencies for you